# Must a sequence be a function on $\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, definition

I saw many books giving definition of a sequence as:

> A sequence $\left\{a_n\right\}$ is a function, $a:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{R}.$

This means that the domain is the set of natural numbers. But there are some sequences for which the first few natural numbers are not the part of the domain.  An example is
$$a_n=\frac{1}{n^2-n}.$$

So will it be more better if we define the sequence as, a function $$a:A \to \mathbb{R},$$ where $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Hmm.  That allows that $a_3$ and $a_5$ are defined, but not $a_4$.

Comment: I suppose you could define a sequence that way, but then we would probably be saying something like "Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence whose domain is $\mathbb N$" $99\%$ of the time? I think for sequences like this where a few terms are undefined, you could simply say let $a_n = 0$ for $n = 0, 1$, and then define it by the formula you want for the $n$ for which it is valid.

Comment: Perhaps as a function from some final segment of $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ would be ok but I don't see the reason to be so rigorous.

Comment: I suppose there are a few times we might prefer a general subset of $\mathbb N,$ such as the primes, but just because we define you example as starting at $n=2$ doesn’t mean we can’t start at $n=0.$ We just define $b_n=a_{n+2}.$ We’d call your definition a sequence because it is essentially equivalent to a sequence. In short: in reality, it doesn’t matter, but on some technical level you are correct.

Comment: [OEIS uses various offsets](http://oeis.org/wiki/Offsets) starting most but not all sequences with $n=0$ or $n=1$, while others star with a larger $n$ and a few start with negative $n$.  Some sequences have a finite number of terms.  But if you do not at least have successive terms, you might want to reparametrise your sequence

Comment: The domain of a sequence can be taken to be any [inductive set](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InductiveSet.html) (in the sense of Russell) which has a single generator.  For example, the natural numbers are generated by $1$ (or $0$, depending on whether or not you take $0$ to be a natural number).  All such inductive sets are isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$ (in the appropriate sense), hence we might as well declare the domain of a sequence to be $\mathbb{N}$.  This may feel like a bit of a handwave, but I think that most authors feel that a more pedantic definition is likely to confuse.

Comment: Technically $a_n = \frac {1}{(n-1)(n-3)}$ so that it is $a_0 = \frac 13; a_2=-\frac 12$ and $a_4 = \frac 13$ and $a_1$ and $a_3$ are undefined is not a sequence.  But as for any infintie $A \subset \mathbb N$ there is a bijection $\phi: \mathbb N\to A$ so that we may define $a:A\to \mathbb R$ via $a_n=\frac 1{(n-1)(n-3)}$, $\phi:\mathbb N \to A$ and $b:\mathbb N \to \mathbb R$ via $b_n = a_{\phi_n}$ is sequence.  In fact we *have* to do that to define *sub* sequences.

Comment: Related: [Are undefined terms allowed in a sequence?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/143780/42969)

Comment: @MartinR I envy your skill at searching for duplicates.  I honestly tried, and didn't find any.  Thank you.

Comment: @MartinR Upon reflection, I think that this question is better stated, and slightly more general.  If I had not answered this question, I would consider marking the older question as a duplicate of this question.  Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: @XanderHenderson: No, I'll leave that to your (or other users) judgement. Formal definitions are not really my thing.

Comment: @MartinR Like I said, I provided an answer, so I am going to recuse myself.  But perhaps others would like to weigh in.  I've mentioned this question in [CURED](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58240610#58240610).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct formal definition is the one you quote: a function with $\mathbb{N}$ as domain.

In the example you offer, the definition of $a_n$ makes sense only for $n > 1$. In practice that's not a problem. If you insist on writing that sequence using the formal definition, you shift the index and write

$$
a_n = \frac{1}{(n+1)^2 - (n+1)}.
$$

(This assumes the natural numbers start at $1$.)

Comment: @mjw As written, that's not a sequence because the function is not defined at every natural number. You could force it to be one in several ways, starting later or writing the function in pieces to skip inputs that make no sense. But there is really no need to bother. If you encounter that expression in practice you will have no trouble working with it in spite of the formal ambiguity.

Comment: @EthanBolker as per your logic can i define the sequence given by mjw as: $a_n=\frac{1}{n^2+5n}$

Comment: @Umeshshankar Your expression does define a sequence since the denominator never vanishes, but it's not the same one as mjw's. The change in sign changes the values.

Comment: @mjw An alternative would be to define $a_n = 0$ for all $n$ where the defining formula would otherwise be undefined.  This gives a slightly different sequence, but we are usually worried about the limit of a sequence, or the series defined by a sequence, so the alteration likely doesn't matter.

Answer (score 6):

Something to always be aware of in mathematics is that definitions are not gospel, they are not written in stone, and they are not handed down by g*d or nature.  The particular definitions we choose are those definitions which we find to be *useful*, and which describe objects which we might like to study.

In the case of sequences, the fundamental underlying intuition is that we have a bunch of objects which occur in succession, one after another.  A sequence has a starting term, and then a next term, and then a next term, and so on, forever and ever.<sup>[1]</sup>  This fundamental intuition leads us to compare an ordered list of numbers (or other objects) to the natural numbers, which are, in some sense, the simplest collection of objects which match the description "there is a first thing, and then other things which occur in succession".

In other words, we can take any sequence and match up the objects in the sequence to natural numbers.  In the modern language of mathematics, which uses functions to do a lot of the heavy lifting, this "naturally" leads to the following definition:

> **Definition:** A *sequence* of real numbers is a function $a : \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$.<sup>[2]</sup>

This is a perfectly good definition for the purposes of most introductory calculus or analysis classes, but, as noted in the question, there are potential problems.  The difficulty in the question is that the asker wants to define a sequence $(a_n)$ via the formula
$$ a_n = \frac{1}{n^2 - n}. $$
Per the definition given above, this is *not* a sequence, as this formula does not define a function whose domain is $\mathbb{N}$.  That being said, a reasonable understanding of this formula is that the author wishes to define a sequence whose first several terms are
$$ \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{6}, \frac{1}{12}, \frac{1}{20}, \dotsc.$$
We *could* say that this "sequence" is defined by the formula above, and concede that it isn't *really* a sequence because $a_1$ is undefined.  Or we could introduce the notion of a partial function, and define sequences to be certain kinds of partial functions defined on $\mathbb{N}$.  Or we could write another, more general definition of a sequence which has as its domain some singly-generated inductive set. Or we could reindex things and define a sequence $(a'_n)$ by the formula
$$ a'_n = \frac{1}{(n+1)^2 - (n+1)}. $$

Or we can just sweep all of this under the rug and ignore the problems with this "sequence", and get on with doing whatever computation we are *actually* interested in.

Most of the time, we ignore these issues.  This is not an unreasonable thing to do, as the definition was written to describe a particular intuition regarding what a sequence *should* be.  We (hopefully) infer that the formula
$$ a_n = \frac{1}{n^2 - n}$$
is meant to define a function $a : \mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\} \to \mathbb{R}$, and get on with our lives.

To get some context for this faffery, you might like to read Terrence Tao's essay [There's more to mathematics than rigor and proofs](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/theres-more-to-mathematics-than-rigour-and-proofs/).  You are correct that, from a rigorous point of view, there is a problem with the definition provided here.  It is good that you spotted it—this indicates that you are comfortably sitting in the rigorous state of mathematical thinking (at least, with respect to this particular part of mathematics).  The trick, now, is to gain comfort with this definition (with all of its flaws), build the intuition, and transition to a post-rigorous way of thinking.  Good luck. :)

---

[1] One might argue that the notion of a "finite sequence" might also be a useful object to study, but let us, for the sake of argument, agree that a "finite sequence" isn't a sequence at all.

[2] Note that we could define a sequence more generically as a function $a : \mathbb{N}\to X$, where $X$ is any set at all.  For example, a function $a :\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{C}$ is a sequence (of complex numbers), and a sequence $a : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is sequence (of $n$-dimensional vectors).

Answer (score 2):

As Xander says, [mathematical definitions are not things to be proven](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1399880/21820). However, I disagree with some points in his post, not because it contains wrong mathematics but because there is a better way from a logic-based viewpoint.

The whole point of the notion of "sequence" is to capture some kind of listing or iteration. So in line with what Xander says, we can **encode** such an abstract notion *via* functions on some **index set** $I$ that are [linearly ordered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) by $<$, using elements from $I$ to tag the items in the sequence to represent their order in the sequence. An item $x$ assigned tag $k∈I$ can of course be encoded as the pair $⟨k,x⟩$, and thus a sequence with index set $I$ can be **encoded** by a function on $I$.

Note that this is just one possible **encoding** of the concept of sequences. It is not the only way to encode sequences. After all, a function on $I$ can also be encoded as a certain kind of set of pairs from $I×S$ for some set $S$, and if you combine both encodings you would get an encoding of a sequence as a certain kind of set of pairs.

The point is that we need an encoding of an abstract notion *only if* that notion is not *inbuilt* into the foundational system we are working in. And for us to consider an encoding *correct*, it must satisfy the properties that we want the notion to satisfy. For sequences, we want to be able to **construct** new sequences, get a given sequence's **length** $l$ or **extract** the $k$-th item from it (where $k≤l$), **concatenate** two given sequences, and so on. Once we establish that some encoding satisfies all the properties we want, then we **define** "sequence" to be that encoding, allowing us to reason about sequences in the way we want.

Is the encoding the same as the abstract concept itself? Well, no. It is the same thing as with 'the' real numbers. The construction of $ℝ$ via Cauchy sequences or Dedekind cuts are **different**, but satisfy the **same** properties we want (i.e. Dedekind-complete ordered field). In short, [we only use $ℝ$ via its interface](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1809216/21820), and [every theorem about $ℝ$ is actually about **every** complete ordered field](https://mathoverflow.net/a/336233).

Likewise, sequences on $ℕ$ (i.e. with index set $ℕ$) are different from sequences on $ℕ_{≥3}$ (i.e. with indices being naturals no less than $3$), but have the **same** properties. That is precisely why we can view things like $(\frac1n)_{n∈ℕ_{>0}}$ as essentially the same sequence as $(\frac1{n+1})_{n∈ℕ}$, even though the two are different encodings. They have the same length, the same items in the same order, and yield the same result when concatenated with a given other sequence.

Now once you hold this general view of a sequence as indexed by some set $I$, it is completely natural to ask what kind of $⟨I,<⟩$ we want to have. While item-extraction and concatenation works for any $⟨I,<⟩$, *length* does not really make sense unless $⟨I,<⟩$ is a [**well-order**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order). This automatically yields the **fully general definition** of a (possibly transfinite) **sequence**, including finite sequences (since $⟨[1..n],<⟩$ is also a well-order, being a prefix of $⟨ℕ,<⟩$), even the empty sequence (with length $0$), sequences of length $ω$ (i.e. the length of $⟨ℕ,<⟩$, and also sequences of longer lengths.

The reason we want to have sequences longer than $ω$ is that there are some circumstances in mathematics where we need to perform a recursive iteration longer than $ω$. A recursive function on a well-order $⟨I,<⟩$ is a function $f$ on $I$ given by a recursive definition $f(k) = g(f{↾}I_{<k})$ for every $k∈I$, where $g$ is some function. Such recursion is well-defined only when $⟨I,<⟩$ is a well-order. Admittedly, almost all applied mathematics does not require sequences longer than $ω$, but it is quite common in modern mathematics.