# Shorthand set builder notation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I was reading some papers and they had the following notation:

$$
\big\{k\big\}_{k=0}^n
$$

I assume this implies that

$$
\big\{k\big\}_{k=0}^n = \{k \in \mathbb{WHAT} : 0 \leq k \leq n\}
$$

What is $k$ an element of? I assume integers, but it might as well be real or complex. I propose a better, less ambiguous notation:

$$
\big\{k \in \mathbb{SOMETHING}\big\}_{k=0}^n 
$$

Would this work better or does this mean something completely different?

Comment: It might also refer to a [sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/143791/21813).

Comment: Could you tell us which papers you found this notation in?

Comment: @MathGeek https://cims.nyu.edu/~sling/MATH-SHU-236-2020-SPRING/MATH-SHU-236-Lecture-6-kmeans.pdf

Comment: IMO it is simply $\{ 0,1,\ldots , n \}$

Answer (score 1):

The notation $\{f(k)\}_{k=0}^n$ in the [context given](https://cims.nyu.edu/%7Esling/MATH-SHU-236-2020-SPRING/MATH-SHU-236-Lecture-6-kmeans.pdf) means either the sequence or set $$f(0),f(1),f(2),\dots,f(n) $$

in analogy to sum or product notation, where $$ \sum_{k=0}^nf(k)=f(0)+f(1)+\dots+f(n)$$

and $$\prod_{k=0}^nf(k)=f(0)\times f(1)\times\cdots\times f(n) $$

Your notation $\{k\}_{k=0}^n$ would mean $\{0,1,\dots, n\}$, but I think the paper is actually using examples like $\{\mathbf{c}_j^{(t)}\}_{j=1}^k=\{\mathbf{c}_1^{(t)},\mathbf{c}_2^{(t)},\dots,\mathbf{c}_k^{(t)}\}$.

Context should indicate whether order is important, if distinguishing between sequences and sets is key.

Instead of your notation, what you might see instead is $\{f(k)\}_{k\in S}$ for some set $S$, again in analogy to sum or product notation.